# Combine 2 counts into a sum in hive sql from union table

Tags: hive, hiveql

I'm having a hard time combining the sum of counts as a result of a union table in hive sql

```
SELECT pulocation AS locID,count(pulocation) AS puCount FROM task1 
  WHERE  distance > 0.5 AND distance < 1  
  GROUP BY pulocation 
UNION
SELECT dolocation,count(dolocation) AS doCount FROM task1 
  WHERE  distance > 0.5 AND distance < 1
  GROUP BY dolocation
```

will give me result of this table

```
_u2.locid   _u2.pucount
1           18
1           24  
3           3
3           4
4           4693
```

I tried to put this table to create a new table with combination of the counts but with no success.

```
SELECT _u2.locid, SUM(_u2.pucount)
FROM (
SELECT pulocation AS locID,count(pulocation) AS puCount FROM task1 
  WHERE  distance > 0.5 AND distance < 1  
  GROUP BY pulocation 
UNION
SELECT dolocation,count(dolocation) AS doCount FROM task1 
  WHERE  distance > 0.5 AND distance < 1
  GROUP BY dolocation)
GROUP BY u2.locid
```

I tried using '_u2.' or 'u2.' but result in this error

```
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 14:0 Failed to recognize predicate 'GROUP'. Failed rule: 'identifier' in subquery source
```

What I basically want is this table

```
_u2.locid   _u2.pucount
1           42
3           7       
4           4693
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as:

```
SELECT t.locid, SUM(t.pucount)
FROM ((SELECT pulocation AS locID, count(pulocation) AS puCount
       FROM task1 
       WHERE  distance > 0.5 AND distance < 1  
       GROUP BY pulocation
      )
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT dolocation, count(dolocation) AS doCount
       FROM task1 
       WHERE  distance > 0.5 AND distance < 1
       GROUP BY dolocation
      )
     ) t
GROUP BY t.locid
```

Comment: though not perfect, but it helps me. idk why hive produce error when have brackets. i put a proper answer. thanks for helping. I add the 'AS' before 't' just to clarify. but it works without it

Answer (score 0):

After the help from previous answer,

```
SELECT t.locid, SUM(t.pucount) AS count
FROM (
  SELECT pulocation AS locID,COUNT(pulocation) as pucount
  FROM task1 
    WHERE  distance > 0.5 AND distance < 1  
    GROUP BY pulocation 
  UNION
  SELECT dolocation,count(dolocation) as doCount
  FROM task1 
    WHERE  distance > 0.5 AND distance < 1
    GROUP BY dolocation) AS t
GROUP BY t.locid 
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

`SELECT locID, sum(totCount) as totCount
FROM (
SELECT pulocation AS locID,count(pulocation) AS totCount
FROM task1 
WHERE  distance > 0.5 AND distance < 1 
GROUP BY pulocation 
UNION ALL
SELECT dolocation AS locID,count(dolocation) AS totCount FROM task1 
  WHERE  distance > 0.5 AND distance < 1
  GROUP BY dolocation
) t1
GROUP BY locID`